# CircleCI does not identify my config.yml from my GitHub repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, circleci

I had tried to use CircleCI to run some tests on my spring project.I have added the config.yml as required, but since I found some of my builds fails. I delete the config.yml and unfollow the git repository to use a different template for the config.yml. But, now CircleCI won’t detect the new .circleci directory even though it is on the GitHub repository. [.circleci on GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIPwC.png)

Comment: the same for us. This morning pipeline works correctly, but now ask to configure a config.yml file on each repos

Answer (score 0):

This concerns an incident with CircleCI, as can be found on [their website](https://status.circleci.com/incidents/dbl16jckzmk3):

[image]

And on their [Twitter channel](https://twitter.com/CircleCI/status/1557384638544355330):

[image]

So UI requests were temporarily disabled, but the issue has been resolved a few hours later.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a link-only question. The answer is "*There is a incident with circle CI*".